# Computation of cohomology of ideal sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $j: X \to Y$ be a closed embedding. Let $I_{X/Y}$ be the ideal sheaf of this closed embedding. Then there is a exact sequence

$$ I_{X/Y} \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to j_{*}\mathcal{O}_X \to 0$$

One use this exact sequence for computation of $H^i(Y,  I_{X/Y})$.

In general it is easy to compute $H^i(Y,  \mathcal{O}_Y)$ and $H^i(Y,  j_{*}\mathcal{O}_X)$. But how does one determine the maps between $H^i(Y,  \mathcal{O}_Y)$ and $H^i(Y,  j_{*}\mathcal{O}_X)$? Are there any references where one can find examples of this kind of computation?

Comment: Are you aware that $H^i(Y,j_*\mathcal{O}_X)$ is nothing but $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$??

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: If $Y$ and $X$ are smooth and projective, you can use Hodge theory to identify your morphism to the (conjugate of) the restriction $H^0(Y,\Omega ^i_Y)\rightarrow H^0(X,\Omega ^i_X)$, which may be easier to analyze.

Comment: The precise description of the maximal rank conjecture for curves sheds light on why this may be hard, even though the context is a little different (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.04906.pdf for a statement of the conjecture).

Answer (score 7):

The computation of the restriction morphism $H^i(Y,O_Y) \to H^i(X,O_X)$ is usually non-trivial (unless you know for instance an explicit locally free resolution of the ideal sheaf of $X$ in $Y$).

On $H^0$ this is quite easy, of course.

For $H^1$ one can act as follows: each class in $H^1(Y,O_Y)$ can be represented as an extension
$$
0 \to O_Y \to E \to O_Y \to 0;
$$
restricting it to $X$ one obtains an exact sequence
$$
0 \to O_X \to E\vert_X \to O_X \to 0;
$$
the restriction map takes the class of the first to the class of the second.

On higher $H^i$ one can use Yoneda representations too, but it becomes more complicated.